# CSS: Why Color code #999 shades are different in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I need to change the HTML5 input placeholder styles as following.

```
input[type="text"]#myInput::placeholder {
font-size: 13px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  color: #999;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

In the above snippet, I have used the colour shade #999, but it is looking think in chrome and IE and very light in Firefox.

My sample code here: https://codepen.io/JGSpark/pen/MMQxER?&editable=true

Kindly try this in Chrome first and Firefox next.

P.S: I am using Chrome 75+, Firefox 67+, IE11

Can anyone please help me to make this look similar across all the browsers?

Comment: Have you try to play with opacity?

Comment: try with this https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firefox in version 19 and beyond by default applies an opacity of 40% (0.4) to placeholder text. Simply just add opacity: 1;

```
input:-moz-placeholder,
input::-moz-placeholder {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: This answer is OK, but Firefox has supported the standard (unprefixed) syntax for some years now.